# Unable to save changes in drupal 7 view

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am trying to make some changes in my Drupal 7 site's view. But it gives me this error

> Changes cannot be made to a locked view.

Multiple users are not logged into the site.

Please any one can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Is multiple user login with ?

Comment: Seems to be a well known problem, check here for potential solutions! http://drupal.org/node/408590

Answer (score 3):

There is a `break lock` link in the view itself. click on the link.

Comment: `break lock` link not visible for me in the view

Comment: If you are an admin user, you can click on that error message itself to unlock the view for editing. Try cleaning your cache also.

Answer (score 1):

What i observed is that when i change the name of my root folder of drupal website on localhost this error occurred.
This can be removed by clicking on break this lock link appearing on top of view itself.

Answer (score 0):

delete the row for "Yourview" in the table "views_object_cache"

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem several times. Please make sure that you have logged in using only one admin account at a time even though you are using multiple browsers. Also, make sure that you have logged out of the admin account in other browsers before you close them.

Answer (score 0):

If you currently logged in as the same user (admin) in more than one browser, Logging out of one fixed the problem.

After logging out if you still have the problem force logout all users (empty the session table)

```
TRUNCATE `sessions`;
```